# Get markup back in jquery listview

Tags: jquery, listview

I have the following JQuery. It works but I cannot figure out how to get back the styling. All the A-Tags are normal hyperlinks. No button icons for the up,dn,del

```
    var ul = $(".song-list-div > ul[data-role=listview]");
    ul.html("");
    if (songListArray.length == 0) {
        var li = $("<li data-icon=\"false\">").append($("<a href=\"#\">").text("No list"));
        ul.append(li);
    } else {
        songListArray.forEach(function(songElement) {
            sIDin = songElement.indexOf("<songId>") + 8;
            sIDout = songElement.indexOf("</songId>");
            sID = songElement.substring(sIDin, sIDout);
            sTitleIn = songElement.indexOf("<songTitle>") + 11;
            sTitleOut = songElement.indexOf("</songTitle>");
            sTitle = songElement.substring(sTitleIn, sTitleOut);
            var li = $("<li data-icon=\"false\">");
            var div = $("<div class='ui-block-a'>").append($("<a href=\"#\">").attr("value", sID).text(sTitle));
            li.append(div);
            div = $("<div class='ui-block-b' style='float: right;'>");
            div.append($("<a href='#' data-role='button' data-icon='arrow-u' data-iconpos='notext' data-inline='true'>").text("up"));
            div.append($("<a href='#' data-role='button' data-icon='arrow-d' data-iconpos='notext' data-inline='true'>").text("dn"));
            div.append($("<a href='#' data-role='button' data-icon='delete' data-iconpos='notext' data-inline='true'>").text("del"));
            li.append(div);
            li.attr("songid", sID)
            li.children("a").click(setCurrentSong);
            ul.append(li);
        });
    }
    ul.listview("refresh");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, this cost me an entire day to find the answer. You need to put .trigger("create") on the PARENT element to get a refresh. In my case I added ul.trigger("create") after ul.append(li);